# Laptop's WiFi only works if it's connected to mobile hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, network-adapter

My laptop started acted weirdly.  Its WiFi only works if I connect it to my mobile's hotspot, it doesn't connect to any other type of WiFi networks.  When I turn my laptop on, it shows the networks but doesn't connect.  After like 5 minutes, it doesn't show any network except the mobile hotspot

I tried many different locations, many different routers, Internet providers and so on.  What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific: will your laptop not connect to wifi, or it gets connected but does not have Internet access?

Comment: when i turn my laptop on it shows the networks but doesn't connect and after like 5mins it doesn't show any network except mobile hotspot

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem, singal too weak or broken wifi antenne.

Answer (score 0):

Lots more information needed - Card/system/laptop/everything! - The easiest way out of this problem is to purchase a USB wireless adapter. Plugin, install, use that instead.

Also, have a look all around the edges of the laptop for a wifi on/off switch, or a wireless symbol on the keyboard. Look for a function key and press that and the wifi key if there is one on the keyboard.

Comment: Asus x54h laptop, windows 8.1, my function keys unfortunately are broken and the wifi one's doesn't do anything...

Comment: Get a USB wifi adapter from Amazon/ebay £5 inc delivery- If your wireless function key is broken it can't enable the wifi.